# Restrict Subdomain from accessing google forms

Tags: forms, google-apps-script

I would like to know if there is a script that can restrict users with sub domain emails from accessing a specific google form?

Example: users with emails ending in @student.contoso.com cannot access a specific form that users with emails ending in @contoso.com can access.

I would greatly appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

If you make your Form with Apps Script, you can make a function to detect the Session.getActiveUser().getEmail() and analize it before to continue.

Check the https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session
and the https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form

Comment: Could you expand on how you imagine the workflow?  For example how you would prevent an identified user from viewing / filling the form? -  Thx